# How to isolate variable $x$ inside $\sin$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

It is probably very simple but my math is rusty and I could not find any method to isolate x from this equation:

$$y = r + (r \sin(\frac{\pi x}{360})) + d$$

I am stuck here: $y - d r = \sin(\frac{\pi x}{360})$

How can $x$ be isolated?

Comment: You have to apply the inverse of $\sin$. See [arcsine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine#Inverse).

Comment: I think you want $(y-d)/r$ on the left. Then use $\arcsin$ as @MauroALLEGRANZA says,

Comment: that was very helpful thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is $$\frac{y-r-d}{r}=\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{360^{\circ}}\right)$$
Now it is $$\arcsin\left(\frac{y-r-d}{r}\right)=\frac{\pi x}{360^{\circ}}$$

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I need. now I can find coordinate x on a circle when y and r given (`d` is not relevant).